# show recaptcha after 5 attemp in php

Tags: php, recaptcha

I want to show recaptcha after user attempts, e.g 3 times in order to prevent attack to my website. It's easy to show a message like `die('your attempts are 3')` or some thing like this. My question is how I can show recaptcha after 3 attempts in php.

```
<?php 
  $attempt = isset($_SESSION['attempt'])? $_SESSION['attempt']: 0;
  if($attempt == 3){
   //show recaptcha with jquery
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this,

```html
<?php
$attempt = isset($_SESSION['attempt'])? $_SESSION['attempt']: 0;
if($attempt >= 3){
      //show recaptcha with jquery
}
?>
```